# ASP.Net C# Variables not storing on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, variables, cookies

So i have the code..

```
int var1 = 0;

protected void cmdvar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var1= var1+ 10;
        lblvar1.Text = var1.ToString();
    }
```

And when clicking this, its great.. it takes the int, adds 10 to it, then displays it.. however it won't display any more than 10, did some playing around and came to the conclusion, that its not because the label isnt updating, it just simply isnt adding 10 to the previous 10 on the variable. What am i doing wrong? What am I mising? Do i need to store the variable info in a cookie or something?

Comment: Your are running into STATELESSNESS! Once the web page has been rendered and delivered to the client, its over. You have to track the state of the variable. This means using hidden form fields, query strings, cookies, etc. If you're doing WebForms, the ViewState can hold values in textboxes and such. It's really a whole different world compared to WinForm.

Comment: You need to use something like `Session` or `ViewState` or possibly a database to persist the value between post backs. Depending on what the data is, how it's used, and how long it needs to "live" will help you determine which method is appropriate.

Comment: Use sessions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the lifecycle of ASP.NET. Storing private fields behind the web page isn't the same as how it works with WinForms. If you want to persist information across post backs you need to store it in some persistent storage i.e. `Session`/`ViewState`/`Database` etc.

```
private int var1 = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // load var1 from cache
        Int32.TryParse((Session["var1"] ?? 0).ToString(), out var1);
    }
}

protected void cmdvar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var1 += 10;
    Session["var1"] = var1; // cache var1
    lblvar1.Text = var1.ToString();
}
```

Comment: IMHO, this should have been a comment unless you're going to provide an example of using `Session` or `ViewState` to track the variable...

Comment: @James, After `IsPostback` check, it would be nice to check if session variable is not `null`

Answer (score 2):

So I would strongly suggest looking into a different platform.  Perhaps ASP.NET MVC... However you can use something like the following to get arround your problem.

```
private int MyNum
{
   get{ return (int)ViewState["MyNum"] ?? 0; }
   set { ViewState["MyNum"] = value; }
}
```

Then just use MyNum as your integer your incrementing.

Comment: I think this would throw an exception if "MyNum" was `null` as you can't cast `null` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Session body, HTTP is a stateless Protocol, once you postback you loose the current variable value,

**Solution**:

```
int var1=0;
protected void cmdvar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

if(Session["var1"]!=null)
var1=int.Parse(Session["var1"].ToString());
else
var1=0;
        var1= var1+ 10;
        lblvar1.Text = var1.ToString();
Session["var1"]=var1;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for explaining about HTTP being a stateless protocol. A lot of people don't really understand how the protocol works. If they did, that could help them understand better a lot of the things, like what happens when a POST/GET occurs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that lblvar1 is a Label control then you can do the following.  The reason this will work is because .NET automatically take care of the state of UIControl

```
protected void cmdvar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var var1 = Convert.ToInt32(lblvar1.Text);
        var1= var1+ 10;
        lblvar1.Text = var1.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this way as there could be issues with cached pages returning expired data.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you have to wrap your universe around statelessness before you will get to producing meaningful web applications.

The ASP.NET equivalent to accomplish state-like behavior is to use the Session collection which is available to every web page.

```
protected void cmdvar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int var1 = (int)Session["yourInteger"];
   var1 += 10;
   Session["yourInteger"] = var1;
   lblvar1.Text = var1.ToString();
}
```

You are obviously setting an initial value for Session["yourInteger"] somewhere else, just one time.

The problem with Session is that it makes your application potentially buggy and somewhat unscalable. The more you use it, the worse on both accounts.